# Get "undefined symbol: cairo_surface_get_device_scale" when use caffe in python

Tags: python, archlinux, caffe, undefined-symbol

After successfully compiled and installed `caffe` and `pycaffe`, I got `undefined symbol: cairo_surface_get_device_scale` when trying to import `caffe` in Python.

```
>>> import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/neozero/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "/home/neozero/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_surface_get_device_scale
```

I have googled that upgrade the `cairo` might help. But it did not help. I use Arch Linux and have every thing upgraded and reinstalled `cairo-1.14.6`, which is the latest version, but it still did not work.

```
$ pacman -Qs cairo
local/cairo 1.14.6-1
    Cairo vector graphics library
local/cairomm 1.12.0-2
    C++ bindings to Cairo vector graphics library
local/goocanvas 2.0.2-1
    A cairo canvas widget for GTK+
local/libtiger 0.3.4-4
    A rendering library for Kate streams using Pango and Cairo
local/pixman 0.34.0-1
    The pixel-manipulation library for X and cairo
local/python-cairo 1.10.0-6
    Python bindings for the cairo graphics library
local/python2-cairo 1.10.0-2
    Python2 bindings for the cairo graphics library
```

Thanks for your help!